# How can I select if a row contains a specific type, not contains select existing row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below. There are three types (A, B, and C) available. I want to create general an SQL query. If a row has type B or type C, the row with type B or C should be listed. If a row has just type A, the row with type A should be listed.

Table;

| Number | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | A |
| 6 | B |
| 6 | C |

The expected result when the query run;

| Number | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | B |
| 6 | C |

How can I create the query?

Comment: What if a Number is both TypeB ***and*** TypeC?

Comment: 2 rows with type B and type C should also be listed. I have edited the question. @MatBailie

Answer (score 0):

I would assign each type a precedence, and only return the types of the highest precedence.

Where two types can be the same precedence *(because you want to return both)*, `RANK()` *(rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`)* will ensure both are assigned the same value.

```
WITH
  precedence AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY Number
            ORDER BY CASE Type WHEN 'C' THEN 2
                               WHEN 'B' THEN 2
                               WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                     END
                       DESC
      )
        AS row_precedence
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  precedence
WHERE
  row_precedence = 1
```

One option to make it a little neater could be to use `APPLY` *(or a join on a lookup table)* to derive the integers outside of the window function's code...

```
WITH
  precedence AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY Number
            ORDER BY type_precedence.value DESC
      )
        AS row_precedence
  FROM
    your_table
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      CASE Type WHEN 'C' THEN 2
                WHEN 'B' THEN 2
                WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
      END
        AS value
  )
    AS type_precedence
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  precedence
WHERE
  row_precedence = 1
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/2Abwpa8p

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but there is one more case. If a Number has both TypeB and TypeC, what do we need to do ? I have edited the question and expected result. @MatBailie

Comment: @zedge08 I was already editing that for the amended question; giving `B` and `C` the same precedence, using `RANK()`, should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Phrasing it in a different way helps finding the right command:

You want to have all rows with type 'B' and 'C', plus those with type 'A' if no other row with type 'B' or 'C' exists for that number.

So the SQL command you're looking for is:

```
SELECT t.Number, t.Type
FROM your_table t
WHERE t.Type IN ('B', 'C')
  OR (t.Type = 'A'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM your_table e
      WHERE e.Type IN ('B', 'C')
        AND e.Number = t.Number
    )
  )
```